# Asp:Label is not displayed when Visible is set to true in a catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, exception

My requirement is to display the timeout message when the SQL query times out and there is a timeout exception. I have added a label in the UI and setting Visibility to true in the code when there is a timeout exception. While debugging it reaches that line where I'm setting the *lblTimeout.Visible = True*  but still the message is not displayed because the label is still hidden.

```
<div id="dvGrid">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTimeout" Visible="false" Text="Your query timed out"></asp:Label>
               <asp:DataGrid ID="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                  <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <input type="Checkbox" name="chkBox" value="Blah" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateColumn>
                  </Columns>
               </asp:DataGrid>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
         </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

VB.Net code:

```
Public Overrides Function ReadData() As DataSet
        Dim con As New SqlConnection()
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim query As String

        Try
            query = "Select * from Employees"
            query = "WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00' " + query 'Added for testing

            Dim cmd As New SqlDataAdapter(query, con)

            cmd.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 30
            cmd.Fill(dataSet)
            
            'Some Code

            Return (dataSet)
        Catch ex As SqlException
            Logger.Error(ex)
            If ex.Number = -2 Then
                lblTimeout.Visible = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Logger.Error(ex)
        Finally
            If con IsNot Nothing Then
                con.Close()
            End If
        End Try
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

I went through some other similar questions and referring to those I placed my label inside UpdatePanel and also tried setting `UpdateMode="Always"` But it didn't help.

Comment: When is ReadData() called?

Comment: It is called where I have mentioned the comment 'Some Code'. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it should work, but keep in mind, that the instant you hit a button, and the page travels up to the server, then it can take 5 seconds, or 20 or 50, and the web page is STILL stuck up on the server. If it times out, then your code is done, an page travels back down to client side, and is displayed. So as long as you realize that the time out message can't appear until everything is done and times out, your fine. But you not see the label until such time the code actually times out. Also, keep in mind that controls set = visible are NOT rendered client side.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to change UpdateMode="Always" or UpdateMode="Conditional" is fine?

Answer (score 1):

Use `panel.Update()` right after `lblTimeout.Visible = True`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).